# How i delete list in json file in python?

Tags: python, json, python-2.x

i have some code and json file like this

```
import json

param1 = "xxxxxx" 
param2 = "11111111111111" 
param3 = "333333333"

with open('data/'+param1+'.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    for a in data: 
       del a[param2]
with open('data/'+param1+'.json','w','utf-8') as f:
     json.dump(data, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4,ensure_ascii=False)
```

json data

```
[
    "11111111111111", 
    "22222222222222", 
    "33333333333333"
]
```

i want to delete the "11111111111111" and save in data/'+param1+'.json, but it say TypeError: 'unicode' object does not support item deletion

any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Your data is a list.  When you iterate over it, `a` is a Unicode string.  Instead of:

```
for a in data: 
   del a[param2]
```

Just remove the item from the list:

```
data.remove(param2)
```

Whole code (Python 2):

```
import json

param1 = "xxxxxx" 
param2 = "11111111111111" 
param3 = "333333333"

with open('data/'+param1+'.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    data.remove(param2)

# Python 2 doesn't take an encoding parameter.
with open('data/'+param1+'.json','w') as f:
     json.dump(data, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Result:

```
[
    "22222222222222",
    "33333333333333"
]
```

Comment: thanks for fast responses, i try this but Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "3.py", line 10, in <module>
    with open('data/'+param1+'.json','w','utf-8') as f:
TypeError: an integer is required

Comment: @Ervan You didn't add the `encoding` keyword to `open`.  See my comment in the code above.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "3.py", line 13, in <module>
    with open('data/'+param1+'.json','w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: @Ervan You must be using Python 2.  I updated the code to work with Python 2 instead of Python 3.  In that case, no encoding parameter needs to be passed to open.  `json.dump` has the encoding parameter but it defaults to `utf8` anyway.  Python 2 is non-intuitive about Unicode and encodings.  Update to the latest Python if posssible (currently 3.6).

Answer (score -1):

Use a.remove(value).

```
import json

param1 = "xxxxxx" 
param2 = "11111111111111" 
param3 = "333333333"

with open('data/'+param1+'.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    for a in data: 
       a.remove(param2)
with open('data/'+param1+'.json','w','utf-8') as f:
     json.dump(data, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4,ensure_ascii=False)
```

Note that this will only remove the first occurrence of value from the list a. If you need to remove all occurrences I suggest a nested list comprehension.

```
with open('data/'+param1+'.json') as json_data:
        data = json.load(json_data)
        data = [[i for i in a if i != param2] for a in data]
```